# jenkins Jira(Zephyr ) Integration not working

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-zephyr

facing issue while integration

```
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins.jenkins\workspace\ZephyrSdkTest
[ZapiTestResultReporter] [INFO] Examining test results...
Build result is SUCCESS
null
Problem parsing JUnit test Results.
Error parsing surefire reports.
Please ensure "Publish JUnit test result report is added" as a post build action
Build step 'Publish test result to Zephyr for JIRA' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

how to publish this SUCCESS FAILURE of build in zephyr on success and faliure as shown below

[image: Tobe published in JiraBoard]

[image: Postbuild action]

Comment: Did you know ... The [Zephyr plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/zephyr-for-jira-test-management/) stores credentials in plain text and has CSRF vulnerability. Public knowledge for last 2 years, still no fix. Didn't even consider installing after that. Not surprised it doesn't work either.

Comment: yes i was aware of it, just trying to POC for client, while working on it stuck with this. Thanks for update

Comment: When a vendor does not provide a simple security fix ( it's well documented how to fix), and even introduces a plugin with such a basic issue overlooked, I think you are doing your client a disservice by even going through a PoC which would expose them to such a vulnerability. When the client says "Let's go to Production", what then?

Comment: I informed it the same first hand on vulnerability, Since on request agree to added POC , which result i got stuck and now keeping this told client to scrapped idea for zepyhr too. Moving to Xray + jenkins